# Use of RegionFunction with Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d, regions

I'd like to plot in 3D a long list of polygons created with `TetGenConvexHull`, but only in regions specified by a function.  Is that possible?  As I have it my `RegionFunction` only applies to some points, and not to my `Graphics3D` `Polygon` data:

```
Show[{ListPointPlot3D[{{-0.57735, 0., 0.8165}, {-0.866025, -0.5, 0.}}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z},z <= .6], 
   BaseStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}, AxesLabel -> {x,y,z},Boxed -> False,
   AxesOrigin -> {0,0,0}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, .1}, {-.6, .6}, {-.1, 1}}],
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.34], EdgeForm[], Red, 
            Polygon[{{-0.57735, 0., 0.8165}, {0., 0., 0.}, {-0.866025, -0.5, 0.}}]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.34], EdgeForm[], Blue, 
            Polygon[{{-0.57735, 0., 0.8165}, {-0.866025, 0.5, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.}}]}]}]
```

[image: Output from above code]

Notice that `RegionFunction` clips the first datum in `ListPointPlot3D` ({-0.57735, 0., 0.8165}), but not the `Graphics3D` `Polygon` as I would like.  I'd like the `Polygon` surfaces to be clipped/truncated wherever they intersect the `RegionFunction` (*not* for the surface to be omitted entirely, given a single intersection location/coordinate).

Perhaps there is a way to transform `Polygon` data into `ListSurfacePlot3D` data, which can be utilized with `RegionFunction`...

Note:  I'm actually plotting a lot of complex polygons (not just 2 planes as in the code above), making me want to stick with `Polygon` and `Graphics3D`.